# Solve the given equation:$\cos\theta = -\sqrt{3}/2$ : List six specific solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Ok I understand that the initial equation is $\theta= 5\pi/6 + 2k\pi$ and $7\pi/6 + 2k\pi$

How do I calculate the other 4 values if  $5\pi/6$ and $7\pi/6$ are my first 2.

Comment: add $2\pi$ to each, subtract $2 \pi$ from each (i.e., look at $k = \pm 1$).

Comment: I don't agry for $\theta =\dfrac{2\pi}{3}+2k\pi$. $cos\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{3}\right)=-\dfrac{1}{2}$.

In fact, $cos\left(\dfrac{5\pi}{6}\right) =-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Comment: I believe you want $5\pi/6$ instead of $2\pi/3$, and then you can select any integer values for k to get as many solutions as you want.

Comment: Can you show me all work since Iam getting weird numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are infinitely many solutions for the noted equation. You can calculate the first solution using a calculator. It'll probably give $5\pi/6$ <del>(you got it wrong there with the $2\pi/3$)</del>. Then you get one set of solutions $\{5\pi/6+2k\pi|k\in\mathbb N\}$. You can find 3 solutions from this set by placing $k=0,1,2$.

Now to get the second set you take $-5\pi/6$ (remember that a negated solution for $\cos$ is also a solution!) which when added to $2\pi$ equals $7\pi/6$. This gives you the set of solutions: $\{-5\pi/6+2k\pi|k\in\mathbb N\}$. Again place $k=0,1,2$, get 3 different solutions.

Add everything together to get 6 solutions.

Comment: This is a precalculus class. I have no idea wht you just stated. Can you show me? Do I put in my calculator $5pi/6 + 2kpi$ let k be 1?

Comment: Yes indeed. If you don't understand the $\{\}$ notation it doesn't matter. You do understand that $5\pi/6+2k\pi$ and $-5\pi/6+2k\pi$ are expressions you can evaluate. Just put $k=0$ - you get one solution from each expression. Then put $k=1$,$k=2$ and so on to get as many solutions you want.

Comment: @user137452 TIP don't believe me or the techniques! Test on your calc and see that these are infact solutions.